# Efficiently ploting a table in csv format using Python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a csv formatted table using Python. So far, I was able to get the result I wanted by reading similar questions on the site, but my solution doesn't seem too "pythonic", nor did I found a very straightforward way of doing this. I am sure there is a more efficient way for plotting a table, so I'm asking this question to learn more about Python and let others have a straight answer for the same problem. Here it goes:

I have a table with data, which have headers and a first column. In my case, it is months and years respectively. i.e.:

> Year,JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DIC
>   1998,,0.78,0.60,0.50,0.50,,,,,0.62,,0.45
>   1999,0.40,0.30,0.28,0.22,0.26,0.50,0.52,0.76,0.89,0.85,0.74,0.67
>   2000,0.58,0.58,0.51,0.47,0.63,0.92,1.00,1.00,0.99,1.00,0.96,0.91
>   2001,0.86,0.83,0.80,0.71,0.83,0.98,1.05,1.11,1.09,0.99,0.87,0.80
>   ...

As you can see, there is missing data too.

My solution was the following:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Import Data
Data=np.genfromtxt('LakeLevels.csv',delimiter=',',names=True,dtype=float)

#Extract data
Months=list(Data.dtype.names[1:])
Years=Data['Year']
Level=Data.view(dtype=float).reshape(Data.shape + (-1,))[:,1:]
Level_masked= np.ma.array (Level, mask=np.isnan(Level))

#Plot
fig=plt.pcolor(np.linspace(1,12,12),Years,Level_masked)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks(range(12),Months,rotation=45)
```

I found the solution was too complex for a very simple task. Is there a better way of achieving the same result or parts of the code I can improve? Maybe even a function that does this automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly do you want to plot it?

Comment: Sorry for not clearing that up. I thought my example code showed it. A pcolor or imshow is fine. Adding labels on each "square" would look good in small tables, although I'm sure that that is answered in other questions.

Comment: I think the correct way of naming the plot I want is "heatmap"

Comment: Given the nature of `numpy` arrays that looks like a straight forward solution, even clever.  Unlike `pandas` `numpy` does not have the concept of a `table`, with both row and column labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my final solution based on @Ami Tavory's answer.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('LakeLevels.csv', delimiter=',', index_col='Year')
sns.heatmap(df)
```

So by using these 2 packages (i.e. pandas and seaborn) I was able to get my desired result in 2 lines!

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for this munging + plotting of data.

I didn't follow through your logic all the way (i.e., the mask), but here is the output of the following two lines (on part of your data):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('stuff.csv', delimiter=',', index_col='year').T.plot();
```

[image]

The more stuff you have (e.g., handling missing data, etc.) - the longer the difference in lines of code will become. Numpy is great, but you should probably use higher-level libraries (built over it!) - for this sort of stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ami. I will definitely take a look at Pandas. As for the result, your answer didn't really get the kind of plot I wanted (a pcolor or imshow kind of plot), but I did get how easy it is to import csv on Pandas. By the way, the masking was done in order to "hide" the nan values in the pcolor plot (if not, I get only 2 colors: one for the data and another for the nan values). Regards.

Comment: @jcdoming I see what you mean. To stress again (although it did reflect in your comment), my point was not to exactly recreate your plot (got lost on the mask stuff), but rather to point out the `numpy` is (IMHO) too low-level for this stuff.

Comment: Simple and perfect. Thank you very much. I'm still switching from Matlab to Python and I didn't know about Pandas until now. This does the trick. Best regards.