# Save Pandas describe for human readibility

Tags: python, pandas

working on pandas describe function.  simple enough code:

df['Revenue'].describe()

output is :

[image]

perfect.  my issue is i want to be able to save this data as either a png or a table so that i can place in a single page.  this is for my EDA (exploratory data analysis) i have 6 main charts or information that i want to evaluate on each feature.  each chart will be a seperate png file.  i will then combine into one pdf file.  i iterate over 300 + features so doing one at a time is not an option especially seeing as it is done monthly.

if you know of a way to save this table as a png or other similar file format that would be great.  thanks for the look

Comment: Are you specifically asking how to turn raw text into a PNG?

Comment: So basically, save a pandas dataframe as an image (PNG specifically) for reporting-purposes. Is that your question? If so, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png) help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Saving as a csv or xlsx file**

You may use **to_csv("filename.csv")** or **to_excel("filename.xlsx")** methods to save the file in a comma separated format and then manipulate/format it in Excel however you want.
Example:

```
df['Revenue'].describe().to_csv("my_description.csv")
```

**Saving as a png file**

As mentioned in the comments, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png) post explains how to save pandas dataframe to png file via matplot lib. In your case, this should work:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from pandas.plotting import table

    desc = df['Revenue'].describe()

    #create a subplot without frame
    plot = plt.subplot(111, frame_on=False)

    #remove axis
    plot.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
    plot.yaxis.set_visible(False) 

    #create the table plot and position it in the upper left corner
    table(plot, desc,loc='upper right')

    #save the plot as a png file
    plt.savefig('desc_plot.png')
```