# WeasyPrint HTML-to-image conversion: how to adapt image size to content?

Tags: python, html, css, image, weasyprint

I need to convert some HTML to an image in Python and I am using [WeasyPrint](https://weasyprint.org/).
I would like the image size to adapt to the content.

When using the following, I get an image which is much larger than content (an A4?):

```
# !pip install weasyprint
import weasyprint as wsp


img_filepath = 'test.png'
html_source = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ciao!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World!
    </body>
</html>
'''
html = wsp.HTML(string=html_source)
html.write_png(img_filepath)
```

[test.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHhfu.png)

---

I have tried to use CSS's [`@page size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40page/size) directive to successfully modify the image size:

```
# !pip install weasyprint
import weasyprint as wsp


img_filepath = 'test2.png'
css = wsp.CSS(string='@page { size: 400px; }')
html_source = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ciao!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World!
    </body>
</html>
'''
html = wsp.HTML(string=html_source)
html.write_png(img_filepath, stylesheets=[css])
```

[test2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYp7X.png)

but I would like the image size to automatically adapt to its content.

Setting `@page size` to `auto` seems to resort to the default behavior from earlier.

Any hint?

Comment: By contrast `wkhtml2pdf` seems to have an option to adapt the image size to its content.