# Pasting Excel Table as Image into Word (Python)

Tags: python, excel, ms-word

I'm wanting to take a range of cells from an Excel workbook and paste them in a Word doc as an image at a certain point. Is this possible with Python? I know pasting a normal table is, but I can't find any modules or documentation regarding doing so as an image.

Comment: If you can get the data from your workbook into a pandas dataframe, you can plot the data into an image as a a table. You can then do anything with that image.  
See here for reference.
  [1]: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#plotting-tables
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png

Comment: Helpful way to go about this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the data from your workbook into a pandas dataframe, you can plot the data into an image as a table using one of many alternatives. You can then do anything with that image.
[See](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#plotting-tables) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png).