# How do I save the table generated by pandas.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, image

[image: read_csv table]

I created a csv file and used pandas.read_csv in order to access it. I used

*euler_tens = pd.read_csv(filename)*

and you can see that this table displays when I simply run the variable name. How do I simply save this image as a png file? This table is exactly what I needed, but now I can't seem to get that image, and I don't want to just screenshot it.

Comment: share the csv or dataframe as text first or check https://stackoverflow.com/a/63387275/1138192

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a pandas DataFrame table as a png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png)

Comment: @BigBen yes, combined with the response below I was able to find the proper additional keyword to make it work with dataframe-image, without Chrome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `dataframe-image` module

```
pip install dataframe-image
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi
 
euler_tens = pd.read_csv(filename)
 
dfi.export(euler_tens, 'dataframe.png')
```

Comment: Thanks! Was able to use this with an extra command table_conversion = 'matplotlib'