# Pandas Styled DataFrame with more than 100 rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to export a series of DFs as .png
When I run the code i receive this error:

**ValueError**: Your Styled DataFrame has more than 100 rows and will produce a huge image file, possibly causing your computer to crash. Override this error by explicitly setting `max_rows` to -1 for all columns. Styled DataFrames are unable to select a subset of rows or columns and therefore do not work with the `max_rows` and `max_cols` parameters

How can I overcome this problem?
I tried to insert "pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)", but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hope this link will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png

Comment: later versions of pandas have max_rows option for pandas Styler output, although i dont recognise this error and it might be related to an external image generating library

Answer (score 4):

I go the same error when trying to use

```
import dataframe_image as dfi
dfi.export(styler,filename+'.png')
```

and my error is solved by adding "max_rows=-1", namely

`dfi.export(styler,filename+'.png',max_rows=-1)`

hope this helps.