# How to center Headers and Common Text of a Dataframe that will create an Image with these values?

Tags: python, pandas

If I want to center the headers to print, we can do:

```
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')
```

But when I try to center all the text in creating an image with the values, they keep positioned not centered:

```
DATA,HORA,CAMPEONATO,JOGO,CANAIS
20/02/2022,08:30,Campeonato Italiano,Fiorentina x Atalanta,"ESPN 2, STAR+"
20/02/2022,09:00,Campeonato Escocês,Dundee Utd x Rangers,STAR+
20/02/2022,09:00,Campeonato Piauiense,Flamengo PI x Fluminense PI,ELEVENSPORTS.COM
```

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi

df = pd.read_csv("tabela_para_imagem.csv")
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')
df_styled = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
dfi.export(df_styled,"mytable.png")
```

[image]

My expected result is:

[image]

How should I proceed to be able to centralize all the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

#df_styled = df.style.background_gradient()
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')

dfi.export(df,"mytable.png")
```

which gives:

[image]

To center also the values:

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

df = df.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'center')])])
df.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'}).hide_index()
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')

dfi.export(df,"mytable.png")
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Hello @SergedeGossondeVarenes, thanks in advance for your help, could you help me to centralize all the values (not just the headers) and keeping ```df.style.background_gradient()``` active? Sorry for asking for this additional information, but I'm really struggling to fit everything into one code.

Comment: @BrondbyIF Jag uppdaterade mitt svar. Happy coding!