# Pandas + Seaborn : compute number of 0 regarding categorical datas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I'm currently struggling with my dataframe in Pandas (new to this).
I have a 3 columns dataframe : Categorical_data1, Categorical_data2,Output. (2400 rows x 3 columns).

Both categorical data (inputs) are strings and output is depending of inputs.

Categorical_data1 = ['type1','type2', ... , 'type6']
Categorical_data2 = ['rain1','rain2', 'rain3','rain4]

So 24 possible pairs of categorical data.

I want to plot a heatmap (using seaborn for instance) of the number of 0 in outputs regarding couples of categorical data (Cat_data1,Cat_data2). I tried several things using boolean.

I tried to figure out how to compute exact amount of 0

```
count = ((df['Output'] == 0) & (df(['Categorical_Data1'] == 'type1') & (df(['Categorical_Data2'] == 'rain1')))).sum()
```

but it failed.
The output belongs to [0,1] with a large amount of 0 (around 1200 over 2400). My goal is to have something like this [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png) by jcdoming (I can't upload images...) with months = Categorical Data1, years = Categorical Data2 ; and numbers of 0 in ouputs).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a seaborn countplot. It gives counts of categorical data occurrences in a certain feature. Use hue to add in the second feature to the visualization:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(data=dataframe, x='Categorical_Data1', hue='Categorical_Data2')
```